# Install Microsoft S/MIME Control for Outlook Web Access

Tags: encryption, email, browser

We are using Outlook Web Access and want to use S/MIME encryption.

There is a Microsoft Guide [for installing the S/MIME control into the browser](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/encrypt-messages-by-using-s-mime-in-outlook-on-the-web-878c79fc-7088-4b39-966f-14512658f480).

Is there any way to get this working on Ubuntu? Maybe using Mono?

Comment: mh... "Note: To use S/MIME on Chrome, your computer must be joined to a Microsoft Active Directory domain and have a Chrome policy to include the S/MIME extension."

Comment: Wow sounds even more complicated then. I know I can join an AD .. but I think the  (other) basic problem here is, that the S/MIME Browser Extension is not available for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try out my [OWA-SMIME4Linux](https://github.com/schorschii/OWA-SMIME4Linux). I would appreciate feedback.